# Matplotlib pixel grid not aligning exactly to pixel

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to generate a pixel grid over an image like so:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 20
im = Image.open("images/sunflower.jpg") # create PIL image
im.thumbnail([size,size], Image.LANCZOS) # resize image (preserving aspect ratio)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im, extent=[0, im.width, 0, im.height])

ax.set_xticks([x for x in range(im.width)])
ax.set_yticks([y for y in range(im.height)])
ax.grid(color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=.5, )

ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)

plt.show()
```

This produces the following result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WndUi.png

As you can see, the gridlines aren't perfectly aligned over the images.

Does anyone know of any solutions? I can make the line-width large enough so each pixel is contained within a cell of the grid, but I'd like the lines to be thinner. The problem persists with any choice of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want these to line up, then turn off the grid snapping to the nearest pixel.  The snapping makes the grid lines sharper but at the expense of a 1-pixel dither:

```
ax.grid(color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=.5, snap=False)
```

[image]

Note however, that the ticks and grid likes are now misaligned - you can turn the snapping off for ticks as well.

Personally not a fan of the snapping behaviour - much more relevant when screens were low resolution, but as hiDPI screens become more common I think this is not a good default behaviour.

Comment: This is perfect--thanks! I'm not sure if I would've found this out even after digging through some documentation :)

Comment: I think it's not very well documented, and inconsistently applied to different artists.